# "Error: GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to calendar.events.import failed with error: Bad Request" while uploading events to calendar

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I am trying to import bulk events from the [Google Sheet tab](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PKvYRP7ptmJWYJEzM5EvxZU53bkgr8ujCaAwY0QuKSA/edit?usp=sharing) to Google Calendar using Google Apps Script. The following code snippet first converts the data into CSV format and then tries to import it:

```
function importSheetToCalendar() {

  var spreadsheetId = "YOUR_SPREADSHEET_ID";
  var sheetName = "✨ CUSTOMIZE";
  var calendarId = "YOUR_CALENDAR_ID";
  
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  
  var csvData = convertToCSV(data);
  
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
  
  var events = Calendar.Events.import(calendarId, csvData);
  
  Logger.log(events);
}

function convertToCSV(data) {
  var csv = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    csv += data[i].join(",") + "\n";
  }
  return csv;
}
```

However, when I run this script, I receive the following error:

> GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to calendar.events.import failed
> with error: Bad Request

This [source](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37118?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop#zippy=%2Ccreate-or-edit-a-csv-file) mentions the data formatting before importing the event to the calendar and the CSV events which I am trying to import also follow the same formatting. Can you please guide where I am making a mistake, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- I thought that in your showing script, `var events = Calendar.Events.import(calendarId, csvData);` is required to be modified. The arguments of `Calendar.Events.import` methods are `resource: Calendar_v3.Calendar.V3.Schema.Event`, `calendarId: string`, `optionalArgs: Object`, and `headers: Object`, respectively. In your situation, I think that `resource: Calendar_v3.Calendar.V3.Schema.Event` and `calendarId: string` are used as the 1st and 2nd arguments. Unfortunately, CDV data cannot be directly used. I thought that this might be the reason for your current issue.
- And also, when I saw your Spreadsheet, I noticed that in order to use the values of the Spreadsheet as `resource: Calendar_v3.Calendar.V3.Schema.Event`, it is required to create the object.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

Before you use this script, please check your timeZone of `timeZone`.

```js
function importSheetToCalendar() {

  var spreadsheetId = "YOUR_SPREADSHEET_ID";
  var sheetName = "✨ CUSTOMIZE";
  var calendarId = "YOUR_CALENDAR_ID";

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var [, ...data] = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var timeZone = spreadsheet.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(); // or Session.getScriptTimeZone() or "### your timeZone ###".
  var reqs = data.flatMap(([summary, startDate, startTime, endDate, endTime, , description]) => {
    if (summary && startDate instanceof Date && startTime instanceof Date && endDate instanceof Date && endTime instanceof Date) {
      return {
        iCalUID: Utilities.getUuid(),
        start: { dateTime: `${startDate.getFullYear()}-${startDate.getMonth() + 1}-${startDate.getDate()}T${startTime.getHours()}:${startTime.getMinutes()}:${startTime.getSeconds()}`, timeZone },
        end: { dateTime: `${endDate.getFullYear()}-${endDate.getMonth() + 1}-${endDate.getDate()}T${endTime.getHours()}:${endTime.getMinutes()}:${endTime.getSeconds()}`, timeZone },
        summary, description
      }
    }
    return [];
  });
  const res = reqs.map(obj => {
    try {
      return Calendar.Events.import(obj, calendarId);
    } catch (e) {
      return e;
    }
  });
  console.log(res)
}
```

#### Note:

- When I tested this modified script using your provided Spreadsheet, no error occurs. The events could be created in the Google Calendar.
- This is a simple modification. So, please modify this script to your actual situation. But, if your actual Spreadsheet is different from your provided Spreadsheet, this script might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

- [Events: import](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/import)

Comment: thank you for your answer. It created events in the calendar. However in `res` I received the following error multiple times: `details: { errors: [Object], code: 400, message: 'Missing end time.' } },
  { [GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to calendar.events.import failed with error: Missing end time.]`

Comment: @EagleEye Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. When I tested my proposed script using a new Calendar and your provided Spreadsheet, no error occurs. I deeply apologize that my script is running with no errors. So, I'm worried that your actual situation might not be the same as your provided Spreadsheet. How about this? If your tested situation is different from your question, my answer is for your provided Spreadsheet. So, please test this on your provided Spreadsheet.

Comment: I am using the script on the same sheet that I shared in my question.

Comment: @EagleEye Thank you for replying. From `I am using the script on the same sheet that I shared in my question.`, in this case, can you provide your Spreadsheet including my proposed script for correctly replicating `details: { errors: [Object], code: 400, message: 'Missing end time.' } },   { [GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to calendar.events.import failed with error: Missing end time.]`? By this, I would like to test it.

Comment: Sure, here is the sheet link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PKvYRP7ptmJWYJEzM5EvxZU53bkgr8ujCaAwY0QuKSA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @EagleEye Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor skill. Now, I noticed that I have miscopied my script. `return [];` was not the correct part, and also, that is different from my tested script. So, I modified the proposed script. Please confirm and test it again.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it ran without error.

Comment: @EagleEye Thank you for replying and testing it again. I apologize that I couldn't notice my miscopy, again. But, I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.